# Subdomains and Unbound forward-zones

Tags: dns, wildcard

When using Unbound with forward-zones, does Unbound accept wildcards to help catch subdomains, or must every subdomain be specified by a separate forward zone?

Let's say there is a domain

```
 example.com
```

with subdomains

```
 s0.example.com
 s1.example.com
 s2.example.com
 …..
 s255.example.com
```

then which if any of the following names will catch all subdomains?

```
 name: "example.com"
 name: ".example.com"
 name: "example.com."
 name: ".example.com."
 name: "*.example.com"
```

This might be considered very basic, but I have searched unbound.net, this site, and elsewhere without finding an answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
local-zone: "example.com." redirect  
local-data: "example.com. A 127.0.0.1"
```

queries for www.example.com and www.foo.example.com are redirected, so that users with web browsers cannot access sites with suffix example.com
source: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?unbound.conf

You can also redirect .dev (choose whatever) extension to 127.0.0.1 for example:

```
local-zone: "dev." redirect
local-data: "dev. 10800 IN A 127.0.0.1"
```

this will redirect *.dev to 127.0.0.1 which is useful for web developers working with vhosts for example.
source: http://wtf.cyprio.net/wtf/2014-06-22-unbound-catch-all.html

Comment: did the trick, thanks. but what about something like `cdn.*.dev.` does it have anyway